How to fix sslhandshake error which occures on small portion of users?
Very small portion of my user  (less than 1%) have constant error
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
ssllabs.com shows server certs are in perfect condition
enter image description here
whatever i tried  the only way i could reproduce it is to make custom  without any valid certs.
Thus I made delegated trust manager in hope to test which certificates might be faulty . However checkServerTrusted was never called.
class LoggingTrustManager(private val defaultTrustManager: X509TrustManager) : X509TrustManager {


    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "LoggingTrustManager"
    }

    override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {
        try {
            defaultTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LocalAnalytics.localCertificates =
                LocalAnalytics.localCertificates + certToString(chain)
            throw e // Rethrow the exception to propagate it further if necessary
        }
    }

    override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {
        try {
            defaultTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LocalAnalytics.localCertificates =
                LocalAnalytics.localCertificates + certToString(chain)
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to trust server", e)
            throw e // Rethrow the exception to propagate it further if necessary
        }
    }

    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
        return defaultTrustManager.acceptedIssuers
    }

    private fun certToString(chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?): List<String> {
        val l = chain?.toList() ?: emptyList()
        return l.map { cert ->
            cert.toString()
            val name = cert.issuerX500Principal?.getName()
            val constraint = cert.basicConstraints
            val notAfter = cert.notAfter
            val s = "principal $name constraint $constraint notAfter $notAfter type ${cert.type}"
            Timber.d("reroute $s")
            s
        }
    }
}
  private fun getDefaultSslSocketFactory(): SSLSocketFactory {
        val socketfactory = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() as SSLSocketFactory
        } else {
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
            sslContext.init(null, null, null)
            val defaultSSLSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
            defaultSSLSocketFactory
        }
        return socketfactory
    }

    private val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = getDefaultSslSocketFactory()

    private fun getTrust(): X509TrustManager {
        val trustManagerFactory =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())

        // Initialize the TrustManagerFactory with null, this will use the default trust store
        val nullStore: KeyStore? = null
        trustManagerFactory.init(nullStore)

        // Get the TrustManager array from the TrustManagerFactory
        val trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.trustManagers

        // Iterate through the array to find the X509TrustManager
        for (trustManager in trustManagers) {
            if (trustManager is X509TrustManager) {
                return LoggingTrustManager(trustManager)
            }
        }

        // Throw an exception if no X509TrustManager is found
        throw IllegalStateException("No X509TrustManager found")
    }
 private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, getTrust())
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(loginInteceptor)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()


